# Telegram API, uploading images to get a FileID in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, bots, telegram

I recently started building a little bot in VB.NET and got pretty far with it. Though, there are quite some things I'm simply not getting far with.
One of these things is uploading an image.

I use the Telegram API as a DLL which is pretty nice so far.
Though, I struggle with uploading pictures.

The code itself is `Telegram.bot.SendPhoto.sendFromFile_id(chat_id, <fileID goes here>)`.

it is pretty much self explanatory, though I have no idea how I can obtain a fileID. The API itself does not explain how to do it, and I'm not that good in reading other codes from other languages and translate them over into the language I'm using at this moment.

Is there any kind of solution for this I could try to use?

Answer (score 0):

Telegram API Document description about FileID ( [Source:Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files) ) :

**There are three ways to send files (photos, stickers, audio, media, etc.):**

1. If the file is already stored somewhere on the Telegram servers, you don't need to reupload it: each file object has a file_id field, simply pass this file_id as a parameter instead of uploading. There are no limits for files sent this way.
2. Provide Telegram with an HTTP URL for the file to be sent. Telegram will download and send the file. 5 MB max size for photos and 20 MB max for other types of content.
3. Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files.

I have same problem and solve  this way :

1.first upload image to cloud and get image url

2.set URL file_ID

C# Code example :

```
String ID = bot.chat_id;
bot.SendPhoto.sendFromFile_id(ID, "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
```